# decoding atttribute for picture tag in HTML5

Tags: html

Is not possible to give decoding="async" to a picture tag ?

```
<picture decoding="async">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. The `<picture>` element is a container to associate `<source>` elements with an `<img>` element.

The `decoding` attribute can be applied to that `<img>` element.

Comment: But what about <source> ?

Comment: Same answer applies.

Comment: There is no attribute called decoding in source. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element

Comment: @anjanesh — Yes. That's why the answer for source is the same as the answer for picture, like I said in my previous comment. `<source>` elements are associated with an `<img>` element by a `<picture>` element. The `decoding` attribute can be applied to that `<img>` element.

Answer (score 0):

directly  element is a container to associate  elements .
decoding attribute applied on that image

Comment: But we can't seem to set decoding="async" to the <source> tag.